# Use mysqli_real_escape_string within function

Tags: mysql-real-escape-string

I'd like to use $mysqli->real_escape_string($query) but I can't figure out what's wrong.
Here is my sqlconn.php file:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_init();
$mysqli -> real_connect($db_address, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if ($mysqli -> connect_errno)
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli -> connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli -> connect_error;
}
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");   

function getRowSet($query) {
    global $mysqli;
    $query = $mysqli->real_escape_string($query);
    $result = $mysqli -> query($query);
    if ($result) {
        return $result;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the real_eascape_string on the whole query, because it's meant to be used only for the parameters, one at a time.

Have a look at the example here:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp

Furthermore, for security reasons it would be better to use the prepare() and bind_param().